# Edit UI Table View, Call Between Swipe And Button Display

Tags: ios, objective-c

Where can I call a method when the UITableViewCell is swiped left just before the delete button is displayed?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //DELETE IS TAPPED


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swipe Gesture should work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    // Do whatever you need to do to the cell.

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to call a method right when the user swipes left before the delete button is displayed.  Is there a way to intercept this earlier on, or is adding a swipe gesture recognizer to the table the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, found a way.  If anyone else is curious, this seems to do the trick just before the delete button is displayed -

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"BAZINGA");
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```